# SQL Grant other user db_owner when creating database

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I would like to set up a MS SQL trigger (or some other mechanism) that would automatically grant some group db_owner permission.

I **don't** want our users to have **db_admin** on the SQL Servers, instead I would like to grant them only **db_creator** but whenever someone creates a database, other users should have access to this database as well.

I have tried creating a SQL trigger:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_DDL_CreateDatabase
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS

DECLARE @databaseName varchar(max)
SET @databaseName = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)'))

EXEC ('USE [' + @databaseName + ']' )

IF IS_MEMBER ('DOMAIN\GROUP') = 1
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'DOMAIN\SOMEGROUP'
ELSE
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'DOMAIN\SOMEOTHERGROUP'

GO
```

Since I can not use `USE` statement in the trigger I've tried using the `EXEC ('USE [' + @databaseName + ']' )` approach - however it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions please?

**edit:** It would be awesome if I can grant different permissions based on the group membership. For example user is member of group A then A is being added to the db_owner, if B then B,C and E is being added etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every database gets created as a copy of `[model]`. Any users, groups and grants you apply in `[model]` will be automatically copied into any newly created database. Note that this does not address databases that are attached.

If you want to do it via DDL triggers you need to use dynamic sql for the *entire* batch:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_DDL_CreateDatabase
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
DECLARE @databaseName sysname;
SET @databaseName = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'sysname'));
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'USE ' + quotename(@databaseName) + N';
IF IS_MEMBER (''DOMAIN\GROUP'') = 1
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''DOMAIN\SOMEGROUP''
ELSE
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_owner'', N''DOMAIN\SOMEOTHERGROUP'';';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

As good practices use [`QUOTENAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to properly escape names. Use `sysname` for database name type, both in extraction (xml method) and in storage (variable type). As it were your code could had been easily exploited by a `db_creator` to elevate himself to sysadmin via SQL injection (create an appropriate db name and pwn you).

Comment: Oh thank you, that's good idea! But what if I want to perform some basic logic like granting permission based on the group membership.